# What is the best way to search for groups of words including spaces?

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

I have a large vector of strings and I would like to count the number of exact occurrences of a vector of patterns. The patterns include spaces but I would like to find only those matches that match the entire pattern.

I would like to return three things:

1. The number of overall matches (i.e. how many of the strings had *any* match in the list of patterns.
2. Which patterns were the most frequently matched patterns, sorted by number of occurrences.
3. Which strings had most matches, sorted by the number of matches.

```
strings <- c("This is a rather long and rather uninteresting string", "This is the second string, which I just came up with")
patterns <- c("Something irrelevant", "second string", "is the")
```

I would like to filter such that "second string" is found in the second element of the string vector but that the word "string" is not found in the first. It should also find "is the" in the second string but not the "is" in the first string.

So there  should be two outputs which should show the following:

```
### Total number of strings containing any of the patterns
# 1

### Individual matches by patterns
# "second string" 
# 1
# "is the"
# 1
# "Something irrelevant"
# 0

### Individual strings by matches
# "This is the second string, which I just came up with"
# 2
# "This is a rather long and rather uninteresting string"
# 0
```

I have tried the following:

```
library(dplyr)
string %>%
     filter(str_detect(., paste(pattern, collapse = "|") %>%
     group_by(pattern) %>%
     count()
```

The major problem I run into is that the paste(...) finds partial matches. In the example above, it would find "is" in both strings. I only want it to find exact matches.

Comment: To match a word as a whole word, use `\b`, word boundary, `stringr::str_c("\\b", paste(pattern, collapse = "|"), "\\b")`

Comment: The `filter/group_by` etc work in data.frame and not on a vector..  Perhaps you can do  `tibble(col1 = strings) %>% filter(map(patterns, ~ str_detect(col1, .x)) %>% reduce(`|`))%>% count(col1)`